SEO Urls in SW6 for a custom entity are only working in dev mode
I have a plugin that contains a custom entity for Shopware and I have dynamic SEO Urls for these custom entities. It's all working fine, I can generate Urls and when put dev in APP_ENV in .env, the URLs are used in listings too or wherever I render the SEO Url with the Shopware twig extension seoUrl(), but as soon as I put prod in the APP_ENV variable, the seoUrl function is returning only the technical URL, like https://example.org/custom-entity/13123...23123
Is this something, someone ever encountered? I really don't know what to do anymore. I tried to find a reason by going down the method calls outgoing from the seoUrl twig extension. But I didn't find anything.
